# Parallel loop in .NET

Tags: .net, parallel-processing

iNewList is 2-4 long every time
ProcessMatch takes on average about 2 minutes
iOld is an outer loop that is not parallel and does not need to be parallel
Basic loop:

```
Int32 nearDupID = 1;
for(int iOld = 0; iOld < 200, iOld++)
{
    foreach (Int32 iNew in iNewList)
    {
        ProcssMatch(iOld, iNew, sIDwordIDs, ref nearDupID); 
        // nearDupID is passed by ref and is revised in ProcssMatch 
        // the next call to ProcssMatch starts with the value from the last call
        // in parallel can I have shared nearDupID - update in one seen by others
    }
}
public void  ProcssMatch (int iOld, int iNew, sIDworkID[] sIDwordIDs, ref int nearDupID)
{  

     bool needNewID = false;
     loop on sIDwordIDs
     {         
        // do stufff 
        // this matches nothing - need a new nearDupID so I set needNewID to true
        if(needNewID)
        {
            nearDupID++;
            // i need a new nearDupID that is unique period
            // not just unique to this parallel process  
            needNewID = false;
        }
        // do more stuff
     }
}
```

Simple parallel is:

```
Parallel.ForEach(iNewList, (iNew) =>
               {
                    ProcssMatch(iOld, iNew, sIDwordIDs);    
               });
```

But that is not passing and sharing nearDupID
The problem is I need to share  nearDupID across parallel ProcssMatch.
In ProcessMatch it will loop like 1,000,000 times and nearDupID will increment like 1,000 times.
How can I share nearDupID across parallel process?

I found Interlocked  [How to: Write a Simple Parallel.For Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx) but I don't know how to pass it around.  I want to pass nearDupID to ProcssMatch.  In ProcssMatch I need to increment the shared nearDupID by 1 and read THAT value. Like I said a ProcssMatch only increments nearDupID about 1000 and runs 2 minutes.

Comment: This is a confusing question. Please include all the code we need to replicate your current processing, i.e. code that we can compile and run. Then we can play with timings and parallelizing and provide you with a solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity I just need help on syntax to share nearDupID across parallel.   There is WAY to much real code to include.   It is processing million of records read from a database.

Comment: It may be logically impossible to share nearDupID across processes.  That's why we need to know its purpose before helping.  It isn't merely a syntax issue.

Comment: @JohnFisher nearDupID needs to be unique.   If it cannot be done then it cannot be done.  I have been researching and I thought that is what Interlocked does.

Comment: @Frisbee - What you should do is write up a bit of code that has the same structure as your actual code, but none of the DB calls etc because we can't run that. But if you can simulate DB calls with `Thread.Sleep` then we can run your code. I don't think this'll be hard to answer, but the current lack of answers so far is directly related to the quality of the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity I will try and make question more clear.  Right now without parallel nearDupID is passed by reference.  So the next call to ProcssMatch gets the prior value.  nearDupID is an identifier that get incremented. Can I deal with that in parallel?

Comment: @Frisbee - You keep asking about `nearDupID` and we keep asking you to post runable code. We are asking for code so that we can answer your questions about `nearDupID`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Increment.  It is just a simple nearDupID++;  I will post it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will help?  It's still unclear exactly what nearDupId is supposed to do.

```
var nearDupId = 1;
Parallel.ForEach(iNewList, (iNew) =>
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref nearDupId);
        var copyOfNearDupId = nearDupId;
        ProcssMatch(iOld, iNew, sIDwordIDs, ref copyOfNearDupId);    
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but I have not had a chance to test.  I appreciate the help but don't understand how the purpose of nearDupID affects the implementation.  As I stated nearDupID needs to be unique.  If parallel one generates a 17 (via ++) and parallel two generates 17 (via ++) then  two nearDupID with a value of 17 that are not actually the same.   If you have two phone operators taking orders and generating order numbers if they are not using a master list of order number then order numbers will collide.